# Visual interpretation of $\sup(A) \leq \sup(B) $

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

By definition for Sup(S):

> $\forall x \in S, x\leq \sup(S)$  and $\forall s_1\in S<\sup(S), \exists x > s_1  $

Is the below visualization of $\sup(A)\leq \sup(B)$ correct? With $X_A \in A, X_B \in B$.

[image]

If so would the following statements about it be equivalent to $Sup(A)\leq Sup(B)$ I think they are from the diagram.

1. $\forall X_B \exists X_A : X_B \geq X_A $
2. $\forall X_B $ and $ \epsilon >0, \exists X_A: X_A\leq X_B + \epsilon $

Comment: No. Even though $Sup(B)\ge Sup(A)$, $B$ may have elements smaller than every element of $A$. Consider $A=\{5\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Comment: @JohnDouma , oh i see, so in the diagram, assuming that it is correct. we can see that $X_B$ over laps onto Sup(A) and there are no $X_A$ smaller to choose from. So is the diagram correct?

Comment: I am not sure what constitutes a correct diagram. It does seem to suggest that the greatest lower bound of $B$ is also greater than the greatest lower bound of $A$ which, as the above example shows, is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very interesting mistake you are making :

> Even $\sup A \leq \sup B$ *does not guarantee that every element of $A$ lies to the left of some element of $B$*.

For example, simply take $A = [0,1]$ and $B = [0,1)$. Then, $\sup A \leq \sup B$ , since both are equal to $1$, but $A$ still contains an element which is bigger than every element of $B$, namely $1 \in A$.

---

Lemma : $\sup A \leq \sup B$ implies that for all $a \in A, \color{blue}{a \neq \sup A}$, there exists $b \in B$ such that $a < b$.

Proof : If $\sup A \leq \sup B$, then fix $a \in  A$. We know that $a \color{red}{<} \sup A $, so $a < \sup B$ and hence there is an element of $B$ which is greater than $a$.

---

Lemma : However, $\sup A \leq \sup B$ *is implied by* : for all $a \in A$ there exists $b \in B$  such that $a < b$.

Proof : For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $a > \sup A - \epsilon$, now find $b > a > \sup A - \epsilon$, and it follows that $\sup B \geq b > a >  \sup A - \epsilon$, for all $\epsilon$, so the lemma follows.

---

In conclusion, $\sup A \leq \sup B$ is sandwiched between two very close looking but certainly different conditions :

- It is stronger than the condition that every element of $A$ *bar the supremum(if it is in $A$)* is strictly to the left of some element of $B$.
- It is weaker than the condition that every element of $A$ is to the left of some element of $B$.

Note that if $A$ does not contain its supremum, then the condition $\sup A \leq \sup B$ is equivalent to any of the above conditions.

---

Therefore, a diagram wishing to illustrate $\sup A  \leq \sup B$ must illustrate that it is sandwiched between the two cases.

Therefore, one diagram does not do the job : many are required. While you have demonstrated a single and correct example, it is still worth noting from above that the condition given to you is a very subtle one. I leave you to decide how to draw a diagram after this discussion.